# Angular radio button show different appearance in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, radio-button, internet-explorer-8

With angularjs, I put a radio button at HTML web page.

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" checked/>man
```

[image: normal checked]

The radio button just show as default **IE8** radio button, but when I change the HTML to below:

html:

```
 <input type="radio" ng-model="sex" id="noLevel1" value="man"/>
```

js:

```
 $scope.sex = "man";
```

when the page loaded, the radio button is checked, but show as below:

[image]

When I click it again, it shows as the first appearance.

This issue does't appear in chrome. The appearance of the above two situations are just same at chrome.

I just wonder how can I fix the problem at **IE8**?
Any information will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is unrelated to AngularJS. It due to some styles as border and background. Maybe you friend fire the radio input when some input need to be styled.